# XCode Simulator Path in XCode 13.2

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, react-native

I tried to download manually the iOS Simulator 15.0 but I don't know where should I put the .dmg file or iPhoneSimulatorSDK15_0.pkg file, Does anyone have any idea where should I put the package in xcode folder?

I tried download manually because I find some errors when I tried download using XCode 13.2.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add simulator IOS 15 dmg file

1. First go to the xcode preferences
2. Tap on Location and Tap on the derive data arrow below derive data
3. Tap on IOS Device Support and add dmg filev in the support file.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I couldn't find the iOS Devicesupport here. There are only DerivedData, iOS Device Logs, UserData, and Archives. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to download simulator are the steps below:

1. Click devices to build

[image]

2. Click Download Simulators

[image]

3. Click download button of the version you want

[image]